# Express server console problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm setting up an Express Server and it's working properly or seems to be. What I send gets rendered in the browser and my console.log test statements show up in my terminal but when I inspect the browser page it is not showing up in the browser console. I've never had this happen before. Any input??

Comment: You're saying the `console.log` that you do inside of the `express` server doesn't show up in your browser console? It won't, these are two different environments.

Comment: Thank you!!! I really thought it has in the past but apparently not lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show express console logs on browsers console.

Comment: Thank you!!! I really thought it has in the past but apparently not lol!